# ORA-04091 on a before insert trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

1. Create a simplest table
2. add a before insert trigger which just counts the table rows
3. insert a row and `ORA-04091 table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` is thrown:

```sql
-- 1. create table
create table cdt (a number)

-- 2. create before insert trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_CDT
  before insert on cdt
  for each row
declare
  cnt number;
begin
  select count(*)
    into cnt
    from cdt;
end TRIG_CDT;

-- 3. insert
insert into cdt(a)
select 1 from dual
```

the above throws:

```
ORA-04091: table CDT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "TRIG_CDT", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TRIG_CDT'
```

However, if insert using `values` instead of `select` it works:

```sql
insert into cdt(a) values(1)
```

Comment: I'd have to search the documentation for the exact details, but I'd say the `insert ... values` syntax defines a single-row insert and so the database knows it won't encounter the problems that could arise with row processing order etc. SQL doesn't like to be told what order to do things in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutating tables are very odd problems. The Oracle mutating trigger error occurs when a trigger references the table that owns the trigger.
**In this case** you can make it work if you declare your trigger as an **autonomous transaction** separating the table from the transaction.
More about the problem here : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_avoiding_mutating_table_error.htm
More about how to avoid it here : https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG_CDT
  before insert on cdt
  for each row
declare
  cnt number;
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  select count(*)
    into cnt
    from cdt;
end TRIG_CDT;
```